# Embedded YouTube Video Stops Becoming Responsive When Browser Window is Shrunk

Tags: html, css

Online I discovered how to make embedded YouTube videos responsive, however, when the browser window shrinks to a certain size the video stops becoming responsive (which I understand) but it is all disproportional, and looks terrible, and goes outside of it's div.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Also, my background picture for the main div is not responsive either when the browser window is shrunk. Can anybody help me with that as well please?

HTML Code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Hyperdog Productions</title>
        <link href="css/stylesheet5.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="navigation_bar">
                <span><a href="index.html" class="logo" id="home">Hyperdog Productions</a></span>
                <ul class="navbar_list">
                    <li class="nav_list" id="about"><a class="nav_link" href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_list" id="short_films"><a class="nav_link" href="films.html">Short Films</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_list" id="cast/crew"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Cast/Crew</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_list" id="contact_us"><a class="nav_link" href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_list" id="other"><a class="nav_link" href="other.html">Other</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </div> <!--End of NAVIGATION_BAR-->
            <main id="container">
                <div id="container_wrapper">
                    <div id="video">
                        <iframe class="trouble_in_smalls" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EuIXJIp8f6U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--End of CONTAINER_WRAPPER-->
                <div id="footer">
                </div> <!--End of FOOTER-->
            </main> <!--End of MAIN-->
            <footer id="copyright">
            </footer> <!--End of COPYRIGHT-->
        </div> <!--End of WRAPPER-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Lato-Regular";
src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.ttf");
src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.woff");
}

@font-face {
font-family: "PT-Sans";
src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.ttf");
src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.woff");
}

* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 1440px;
width: 100%;
font-size: 0;
overflow-x: none;
}

body {
font-size: 62.5%;
min-width: 575px;
}

.wrapper {
height: 1440px;
}

#navigation_bar {
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

main {
height: 1300px;
}

#container_wrapper {
height: 900px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("../images/landscape.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
}

#footer {
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat;
text-align: center;
}

#copyright {
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

.logo {
padding: 9px 12px;
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
float: left;
left: 20%;
top: 25px;
font-family: "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
letter-spacing: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #000000;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #AF7817; /* Cool Light Blue Color: #708090 */
}

.logo:hover {
color: #B8860B;}

.navbar_list {
position: absolute;
float: right;
right: 20%;
top: 16.25px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar_list li {
list-style-type: none;
list-style: none;
float: left;
display: inline;
padding: 9px 12px;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 10px;
}

.nav_link:link {
padding: 10px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: "Lato-Regular", "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
font-size: 1.2em;
line-height: 3.7em !important;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
}

.nav_link:hover {
color: #a3a3a3;
}

#video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 640px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.trouble_in_smalls {
position: absolute;
top: 15%;
left: 25%;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 1750px) {
.logo {
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: inherit;
    left: inherit;
    }
.navbar_list {
    padding-left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    float: inherit;
    display: inline-block;
    right: inherit;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the background image not being responsive - you should use `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center` or whatever you want to position your background image.

As for the video, if you want it to not overflow the parent, just add to parent `overflow:hidden` as for the responsive side - your videos heigth is fixed, so whenever you resize your browser it changes aspect ratio, if you do not care for old browser support you can use `vw` units for height and width instead of `px`
e.g. if I wanted my video to be always 16:9 and to be 80% of browsers width I would set `iframes` height and width to `height:80vw; width:45vw` this would be an easy and fast fix